# Complete stack traces from Hyperic

Tags: monitoring, log-files, logging, hyperic

I've setup Hyperic to run on our CI-machine, and every once in a while it reacts to some random stack trace and sends of an alert. So far so good, we've caught a lot of intermittent bugs that way.

My only issue is that the alert only contains the first error line and not the entire stack trace, which requires me to access the machine and look at the logs manually. Is there any way to modify the alert message to contain more information, alternatively to include the log file in the alert mail?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Thanks, M.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone else will be able to expand on this, but from the Hyperic docs, it appears that [Log Tracking](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/Log+Tracking) can be enabled to grab more than one line through the [Edit Alert](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/ui-Alert.Edit) tool.

This *might* be doable via the [New Alert](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/ui-Alert.New) method, as well.

I'd also look at the [Alert and Notification](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/Controlling+Alert+and+Notification+Volume) pages - as it looks like the default is to only get one line, but it may be alterable therein as well. Or perhaps the [Reporting](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/Reporting+Overview) section?

I've not used Hyperic before, so am making a stab entirely off the manual :)

Comment: Sorry, been through all that stuff already, found nada :/

Comment: sorry :-\ ..it was my best guess